# Scrapy how to crawl pagination in second level or nested pagination

Tags: python, scrapy

I am trying to crawl a paginated list of `Catalog` which **works fine**.

But for **each** `Catalog` there is a **paginated list of** `DataSet` but **only first page over there is appearing in the result**. I am trying to get a result that looks like this, but all `24` nodes should be there corresponding to `24` DataSet's spanning over pages of 6 items each.

```
[{'data_sets_count': 24,
  'description': 'The catalog contains data regarding various indicators of '
                 'HMIS like Health, Abortions, Immunisation, AEFI, Adolescent, '
                 'Bite, Sting, Disease, Diarrhoeal, Hypertension, HIV, AIDS, '
                 'Malaria, Neurological, Stroke, Fever, Respiratory, '
                 'Infection, suicide, Trauma, Accident, Burn, Tuberculosis, '
                 'VHND, ASHA, JSY, CHC, PHC, SDH, DH, Hospital.',
  'last_updated': '11/08/17',
  'ministry_department': 'Ministry of Health and Family Welfare, Department of '
                         'Health and Family Welfare',
  'nodes': [{'node': '3183861',
             'title': 'Item-wise report for North Goa of Goa upto '
                      'April-2014-15'},
            {'node': '3183881',
             'title': 'Item-wise report for North Goa of Goa upto May-2014-15'},
            {'node': '3183981',
             'title': 'Item-wise report for North Goa of Goa upto '
                      'October-2014-15'},
            {'node': '3184021',
             'title': 'Item-wise report for North Goa of Goa upto '
                      'December-2014-15'},
            {'node': '3184061',
             'title': 'Item-wise report for North Goa of Goa upto '
                      'February-2014-15'},
            {'node': '3183961',
             'title': 'Item-wise report for North Goa of Goa upto '
                      'September-2014-15'}],
  'state_department': None,
  'title': 'HMIS sub district level item-wise monthly report of Goa',
  'url': '/catalog/hmis-sub-district-level-item-wise-monthly-report-goa'}]
```

---

```
import scrapy
class Category(scrapy.Item):
    title = scrapy.Field()
    url = scrapy.Field()
    ministry_department = scrapy.Field()
    description = scrapy.Field()
    state_department = scrapy.Field()
    last_updated = scrapy.Field()
    data_sets_count = scrapy.Field()
    data_sets = scrapy.Field()
    item = scrapy.Field()
    nodes = scrapy.Field()

class CatalogSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'catalogspider'
    start_urls = ['https://data.gov.in/catalogs#sort_by=created&sort_order=DESC&items_per_page=9&page=1']

    def parse(self, response):
        for catalog in response.css('.view-catalogs > div > .views-row-6'):
            category = Category()
            category['title'] = catalog.css('.views-field-title .field-content a::text').extract_first()
            category['url'] = catalog.css('.views-field-title .field-content a::attr(href)').extract_first()
            category['ministry_department'] = catalog.css('.views-field-field-ministry-department .field-content ::text').extract_first()
            category['description'] = catalog.css('.views-field-body .field-content ::text').extract_first()
            category['state_department'] = catalog.css('.views-field-field-state-department .field-content ::text').extract_first()
            category['last_updated'] = catalog.css('.views-field-changed .field-content ::text').extract_first()
            category['data_sets_count'] = int(catalog.css('.views-field-resource-count-last .count-resource::text').re(r'\((.*?)\)')[0])
            category['nodes'] = []
            request = scrapy.Request(response.urljoin(category['url']), callback=self.parseDataSets)
            request.meta['item'] = category
            yield request

        for next_page in response.css('li.pager-next > a'):
            yield response.follow(next_page, self.parse)


    def parseDataSets(self, response):
        item = response.meta['item']

        for dataset in response.css('.view-resource-detail-popup > div > .views-row'):
            item['nodes'].append({
                'node' : dataset.css('.data-extension.csv::attr(class)').extract_first().split()[0],
                'title' : dataset.css('.views-field-title .field-content .title-content::text').extract_first()
                })

        for next_page in response.css('li.pager-next'):
            print('here')
            request = scrapy.Request(response.urljoin(next_page.css('a::attr(href)').extract_first()), callback=self.parseDataSets)
            request.meta['item'] = item

        yield item
```

Comment: Could you post crawl log? You can do this via `scrapy crawl spider --logfile output.log` or `scrapy crawl spider 2>1 | tee output.log` commands (the later puts output to screen and file).

Comment: @Granitosaurus I just got it working with some changes in code, I'll post the working code now, but not sure if it is the *right* way to do it.

Comment: I'm adding to a meta variable, the items in each child page and yields zero, at the end yields the meta variable when it is the last page. Sounds a bit hacky, but works now.

Comment: @Granitosaurus I'll come back to see **your** version of the same code if you could add one :)

Answer (score 1):

I got it working by using below code, I'm not sure it this is the correct way to do. I'm adding `DataSet` to a meta variable `category` , and yields `None`, at the end yields the meta variable `category` when it is the **last page**. Sounds a bit hacky, but works now.

```
import scrapy
class Category(scrapy.Item):
    title = scrapy.Field()
    url = scrapy.Field()
    ministry_department = scrapy.Field()
    description = scrapy.Field()
    state_department = scrapy.Field()
    last_updated = scrapy.Field()
    data_sets_count = scrapy.Field()
    data_sets_actual_count = scrapy.Field()
    data_sets = scrapy.Field()
    item = scrapy.Field()
    nodes = scrapy.Field()

class CatalogSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'catalogspider'
    start_urls = ['https://data.gov.in/catalogs#sort_by=created&sort_order=DESC&items_per_page=9&page=1']

    def parse(self, response):
        for catalog in response.css('.view-catalogs > div > .views-row-6'):
            category = Category()
            category['title'] = catalog.css('.views-field-title .field-content a::text').extract_first()
            category['url'] = catalog.css('.views-field-title .field-content a::attr(href)').extract_first()
            category['ministry_department'] = catalog.css('.views-field-field-ministry-department .field-content ::text').extract_first()
            category['description'] = catalog.css('.views-field-body .field-content ::text').extract_first()
            category['state_department'] = catalog.css('.views-field-field-state-department .field-content ::text').extract_first()
            category['last_updated'] = catalog.css('.views-field-changed .field-content ::text').extract_first()
            category['data_sets_count'] = int(catalog.css('.views-field-resource-count-last .count-resource::text').re(r'\((.*?)\)')[0])
            category['nodes'] = []
            request = scrapy.Request(response.urljoin(category['url']), callback=self.parse_data_sets)
            request.meta['category'] = category
            yield request

        #for next_page in response.css('li.pager-next > a'):
        #    yield response.follow(next_page, self.parse)


    def parse_data_sets(self, response):
        category = response.meta['category']
        datasets = response.css('.view-resource-detail-popup > div > .views-row')
        if datasets:
            for dataset in datasets:
                node = dataset.css('.data-extension.csv::attr(class)').extract_first().split()[0]
                title = dataset.css('.views-field-title .field-content .title-content::text').extract_first()
                url = 'https://data.gov.in/node/' + node + '/download'
                category['nodes'].append({
                    'node' : node,
                    'title' : title,
                    'url' : url
                    })
                yield None
        else:
            yield category

        if len(response.css('li.pager-next').extract()) == 0:
            category['data_sets_actual_count'] = len(category['nodes'])
            yield category

        #pagination
        for next_page in response.css('li.pager-next'):
            request = scrapy.Request(response.urljoin(next_page.css('a::attr(href)').extract_first()), callback=self.parse_data_sets)
            request.meta['category'] = category
            yield request
```

One of my problem was setting wrong depth in my command, which i changed to a bigger number later, random issues when in unknown domains:

```
 scrapy parse --spider=catalogspider -d 60 'https://data.gov.in/catalogs#sort_by=created&sort_order=DESC&items_per_page=9&page=1'
```